# Creating Emails from Excel Data

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a excel sheet with 3 columns A = Email, B = Name, C = yes or no.
The current code I have will email all the users in the spreadsheet except I need it to send 20-25 emails than pause for a minute and send the next 20-25 than pause for a minute and so on.

```
Sub Test1()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Bcc = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Submittal Exchange Subcontractor Training Invitation"
            .Attachments.Add "C:\subinvite\planswift.png"
            .HTMLBody = "<font size=""2"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
                "Hello " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
                  & "," & _
                "<B><br><br>You are invited to participate in an upcoming Submittal Exchange training session.</B><BR><BR>Please note that our subcontractor trainings are ongoing, in that they are held twice a week, every week, and the information in this email invitation never changes, so please feel free to join us on any Tuesday or Thursday that is convenient for you!<BR><BR>" & _
                "<B>EVERY Tuesday at 1:30PM Central Standard Time</B> (2:30 PM Eastern, 12:30 PM Mountain, 11:30 PM Arizona, 11:30 AM Pacific, 10:30 AM AKST)<BR><B>Tuesday's Meeting ID:</B>  168303738<BR><B>Tuesday's Conference Call Number:</B> 1-636-277-0132<BR>" & _
                "OR<BR><B>EVERY Thursday at 10:00 AM Central Standard Time</B> (11 AM Eastern, 9 AM Mountain, 8 AM Arizona, 8 AM Pacific, 7 AM AKST)<BR><B>Thursday's Meeting ID:</B> 966677330<BR><B>Thursday's Conference Call Number:</B> 1-213-493-0602<BR><BR><U>How to participate:</U><BR>" & _
                "&emsp;&emsp;-&emsp;You can join the web meeting from your computer in your office, no travel needed.<br>&emsp;&emsp;-&emsp;You also will need a telephone to dial in to the conference call.<br>&emsp;&emsp;-&emsp;The training will last no more than 30 minutes.<br><br>" & _
                "<u>Instructions to join the web meeting:</u><br>&emsp;1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Go to the Submittal Exchange public website (www.submittalexchange.com) and click on the<br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&Prime;Join A Go-To-Meeting&Prime; link in the lower right hand corner under &Prime;Quick Links&Prime;<br><br>" & _
                "&emsp;OR<br>&emsp;If you are already logged in to Submittal Exchange, open the website, click on &Prime;Help&Prime; in the upper right corner, then click on the blue &Prime;Meet Now&Prime; button which is underneath &Prime;Join a Training&Prime;<br>&emsp;2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter the nine digit meeting number:<br>" & _
                "&emsp;3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click &Prime;OK&Prime;, &Prime;Yes&Prime;, or &Prime;Run&Prime; if the web meeting software prompts you for permission<br>&emsp;4.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dial in to the conference call number when prompted to do so<br><br>" & _
                "You are receiving this invitation because you have been added to the Submittal Exchange system as a subcontractor or contractor working for a GC or CM. If this information is not correct, please let us know. You should have received a separate email with your username and password information in order to log in to Submittal Exchange.<br><br>" & _
                "If you have already attended a training session, please let us know and we will remove you from our reminder list.<br><br>Or, if you are unable to attend a live training session, the subcontractor training is available as a video demonstration on our Help Page. To access the Help Page, log into Submittal Exchange and click the<br>" & _
                "Help link in the upper right hand corner of your screen. The subcontractor training video is located in the Trainings tab. The video is also a great resource if you were able to attend the live training and simply need a refresher later on. Our Help Page provides<br>immediate assistance for you 24/7. Look for and click on either the Help link or the green question mark to get tips on how to use the system, watch<br>demonstration videos, and more.<br>Thank you!<br><br>" & _
                "<b>EXPLORE ANOTHER GREAT TEXTURA SOLUTION SPECIFICALLY FOR SUBCONTRACTORS!</b><br><br>" & _
                "<html><body><div style=""width:200px;""><a href=""http://www.planswift.com/?AID=2572""><img src=""cid:planswift.png""><\img><\a><br></div><div style=""width:200px; text-align:left; float:right;""><b>Save time and money with the #1 Takeoff and Estimating software.<br><br>Download a Free 14 Day Trial of PlanSwift.<br><br>PlanSwift is the fastest and easiest to use software for accurately completing construction takeoffs on your computer screen. With PlanSwift's visual point-and-click interface, users can drag and drop individual products or assembled product groups directly onto a digitized blueprint. PlanSwift calculates the takeoffs automatically - saving valuable time and effort.</b><br></div></body><html>" & _
                ""
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        'increment counter and wait 60 seconds if it is 25 or higher
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter >= 25 Then
            Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:60")
            counter = 0
        End If
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Updated with @Aiken suggestion.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "pause for a minute"?  Do you mean "the code should pause for X number of seconds before continuing" or "the code should stop sending emails until I click a button" sort of thing?

Comment: The code should pause for 60 seconds than continue down the list of email addresses in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using `Application.Wait` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) and adding a counter to your `For Each` loop.

Simplified Example:

```
Dim counter As Integer
'...
For Each cell in Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
         '###########
         'Email Code
         '###########

         'increment counter and wait 60 seconds if it is 25 or higher
         counter = counter + 1
         If counter >= 25 Then
             Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("0:01:00")
             counter = 0
         End If
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Hmmm it counts to 25 and stops but doesnt continue after 60 seconds.

Comment: My bad, made a silly mistake with the code. You can't use a value of seconds in TimeValue greater than 59. Due to the error handling in your code this was throwing a Type Mismatch error which is taking you immediately to `cleanup:` and ending the code, hence why nothing was happening after 25 emails. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using this newHour = Hour(Now())
                    newMinute = Minute(Now())
                    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 60
                    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
                    Application.Wait waitTime